# Error while writing to the SDRAM

Tags: microcontroller

I am working on the STM32F7xxx microcontroller. I am quite new to the entire microcontroller programming. I am using the latest STM32F7xxx libraries to build my code. I am using this microcontroller for a SLAM application. Since it doesn't have enough memory I want to save the pose information of the robot in the SDRAM. I use the libraries available at : http://stm32f4-discovery.com/2015/07/hal-library-11-sdram-for-stm32fxxx/

The code to write a float value to the SDRAM is quite simple, just a line:

```
    #define TM_SDRAM_WriteFloat(address, value)    (*(__IO float *) (SDRAM_START_ADR + (address)) = (value))
```

My code where I use it is as following:

```
    void write_Landmark()
    {
    int address = uwIndex_lm;
    SDRAM_Write8(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->landmark_index);
    address = address +1;
    SDRAM_WriteFloat(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->pos_x);
    address = address +4;
    SDRAM_WriteFloat(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->pos_y);
    address = address +4;
    SDRAM_WriteFloat(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->pos_theta);
    address = address +4;
    SDRAM_Write16(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->jump_point);
    address = address +2;
    SDRAM_Write8(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->landmark_detected);
    address = address +1;
    SDRAM_Write8(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->landmark_corrected);
    address = address +1;
    SDRAM_WriteFloat(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->hall_angle);
    address = address +4;
    SDRAM_WriteFloat(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->hall_distance);
    address = address +4;
    SDRAM_Write8(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->on_curve);
    address = address +1;
    uwIndex_lm = address;
   }
```

The code execution gets stuck at the line where I write float to SDRAM. But if instead of

```
    SDRAM_WriteFloat(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->pos_x);
```

I write,

```
    SDRAM_Write32(LANDMARK_START_ADR+address,lm_head->pos_x);
```

it works fine. I do understand that I am getting a hard fault here, but I don't really get how to fix this.Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you might need to account for some oddities of pointer arithmetic. What is the size of a float on your platform?

Comment: It is 4 . And I feel the problem isn't really float here. Maybe this isn't the best way to write different data types to SDRAM ? Has any attempted something similar?

Comment: I just realized that alignment is the culprit. So I assigned a space of 4 to all the variables I want to write to the Sdram and it wirks fine :) Thanku ssnobody and Shotgun Ninja for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that alignment is the culprit. So I assigned a space of 4 to all the variables I want to write to the Sdram and it works fine